# How can I show last two pages under a toggle by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to show last two pages under a toggle remaining pages as usual like normal menu, on mobile, using Elementor pro WordPress. What should I do?

Comment: Do the latest two pages mean visited web pages? or pagination maybe? there are a few pagination plugins like https://github.com/josecebe/twbs-pagination

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question does not appear to show any attempt to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try solving your own issue before asking for help. Your attempts will both motivate members to reply and help them understand what you expect. Please edit your question in order to include what you've tried so far following the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).